# Maximal size of familes of subsets with no union.

Tags: extremal-combinatorics

I'm looking for the answer of following problem: Find the maximal size of $S\subseteq 2^{[n]}$ such that there are no distinct $A,B,C\in S$ such that $A\cup B\not = C$. <s>A possible construction is all set of
odd size, which $\#S=2^{n-1}$.</s> A possible construction is all set of
size $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$, which $\#S={n\choose {\lfloor n/2\rfloor}}$. Is this maximal?

---

I've found https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.03659.pdf. There is reference in that which Kleitman give an upper bound $(1+o(1)){n\choose {\lfloor n/2\rfloor}}$. Seemingly that's an open problem for an exact number.

Comment: All sets of odd size is not going to work in general. $A=\left\{1,2,3\right\}$ and $B=\left\{1\right\}$ have odd size but so does $A\cup B=A$.

Comment: @Andijvie yes I made a mistake here. I guess $n\choose{n/2}$ might be the correct answer

Comment: The paper you reference defines a union-free family as a collection $F$ such that there are no three *distinct* sets $A,B,C\in F$ with $A\cup B=C$. This does not forbid the case $A\subset B=C$. Do you mean to use this definition too?

Comment: The families meeting the condition you've currently written are precisely the antichains with respect to set inclusion, so [Sperner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner's_theorem) applies.

Comment: @Karl, yes I overlooked that, I should include this condition.